# How can I copy jQuery extend?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement jQuery's extend method. Then I copied and adapted the source:

```
function extend(deep, target, source)
{
    var copy, original, clone;
    for (var attr in source)
    {
        copy = target[attr];
        original = source[attr];

        if (target === original)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (deep && original && typeof(original) === "object")
        {
            if (original instanceof Array)
            {
                clone = copy && (copy instanceof Array) ? copy : [];
            }
            else
            {
                clone = copy ? copy : {};
            }

            target[attr] = extend(deep, clone, original);
        }
        else if (original !== undefined)
        {
            target[attr] = original;
        }
    }

    return target;
}
```

However, this is throwing a

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

While jQuery method doesn't, for the following code:

```
function Person( params) {
    this.id = params['id'];
    this.name = params['name'];
    this.father = null;
    this.toString = function() { return this.name };
}

var me = new Person({ id: 1, name: 'Luke'});
var him = new Person({ id:2, name: 'Darth'});
me.father = him; 
him.father = me; // time travel assumed :-)

var jQueryCopy = $.extend(true, {}, him); // ok
var copy = extend(true, {}, me); // exception
```

See this [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZCPB/).

Why is my method throwing this exception while jQuery method isn't?

Comment: You have a stack overflow (hah). Your end condition is incorrect. You need to keep a list of properties you've extended before to prevent circular references.

Comment: Well yeah... I didn't know what exactly was wrong, that is why I asked... Solved it now.